# Find the age of the oldest file in one line or return zero

Tags: shell-script, files, directory

I want to find the age of the oldest file in a certain directory or return 0 if there aren't any files in this directory. I also need a one-line command doing it. So far this is my command for finding the age in seconds of the oldest file in the directory:

```
expr $(($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $(ls -lt /path/to/dir/ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'))))
```

The problem is that if there are no files it is returning the following error:

```
$ expr $(($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $(ls -lt /path/to/dir/ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'))))
stat: cannot stat ‘0’: No such file or directory
-bash: 1554373460 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")
```

So in this case I want the command to return just 0 and to suppress the error printout.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it have to be in one line? It's much less readable & maintainable that way.

Comment: I am passing this line to specialized software. Then according to the output of the command, I can trigger an alarm and if I make it on more than a single line, I need to write more complex logic. The idea is to check a specific directory where there should not be any files for more than 20 seconds, I want to trigger an alarm if the age of the oldest file is more than 30 seconds.

Comment: also I would be very happy if you have any ideas, how I can simplify my command for finding the age of the oldest file

Comment: `ls -lt | tail -1` will give you the oldest file; you can parse out the date or go through the `stat` stuff without having to do a single line shell loop

Comment: @mpez0 this is exactly what I am doing, check my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it must be one line:

```
stat -c %Y ./* 2>/dev/null | awk -v d="$(date +%s)" 'BEGIN {m=d} $0 < m {m = $0} END {print d - m}'
```

- `stat -c %Y ./* 2>/dev/null` print the timestamp of all files, ignoring errors (so no files results in no output)
- With awk:

  - `-v d="$(date +%s)"` save the current timestamp in a variable `d`
  - `BEGIN {m=d}` initialize `m` to `d`
  - `$0 < m {m = $0}` keeping track of the minimum in `m`
  - `END {print d - m}` print the difference.

Comment: unfortunately, it does return 0 no matter if the directory is empty or it has more than one file

Comment: @George ah, oops, I inverted the check for min

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh` and `perl`:

```
perl -le 'print 0+-M $ARGV[0]' /path/to/dir/*(N-Om[1])
```

(add the `D` glob qualifier if you also want to consider hidden files (but not `.` nor `..`)).

Note that for symlinks, that considers the modification time of the file it resolves to. Remove the `-` in the glob qualifiers to consider the modification time of the symlink instead (and use `(lstat$ARGV[0] && -M _)` in `perl` to get the age of the symlink).

That gives the age in days. Multiply by 86400 to get a number of seconds:

```
perl -le 'print 86400*-M $ARGV[0]' /path/to/dir/*(N-Om[1])
```

- `(N-Om[1])`: glob qualifier:

  - `N`: turns on `nullglob` for that glob. So if there's no file in the directory, expands to nothing causing `perl`'s `-M` to return `undef`.
  - `-`: causes next glob qualifiers to apply on the target of symlinks
  - `Om`: reverse (capital) order by modification time (so from oldest to newest like `ls -rt`)
  - `[1]`: select first matching file only
- `-M file`: gets the age of the content of the file.
- `0+` or `86400*` force a conversion to number (for the `undef` case).

Comment: I am getting just 0 as an output even though it should show me a couple of thousands of seconds, both commands actually gives me the same output and on another machine I am getting an error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`, the one giving me an error is running a rather old version of perl: `v5.16.3`

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov, the syntax is for `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: I missed that part :) Thanks for the answer @Stephane